# Redirect all wordpress posts to a sub-directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, post, blogs, redirect

I'm moving a wordpress blog from root to `http://website.com/blog`. Consequently I need to redirect links such as `http://www.website.com/2015/05/post-title` to `http://www.website.com/blog/2015/05/post-title`, `http://www.website.com/2014/03/post-title` to `http://www.website.com/blog/2014/03/post-title`, etc. I couldn't find how to do so correctly with .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the top of your htaccess file in your **Document root**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. I have a Joomla site on website.com root, and wordpress blog on website.com/blog root. I tried adding to either one but it didn't work.